# what is the formula to calculate the irreducible fraction series as sum?

Tags: summation, fractions

I have a series like

```
sum = 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... ... ... + 1/n
```

Suppose I know the value of `n`. so what is the formula to calculate `sum`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is no 'nice' closed formula for this. It's known that
$$ \sum_{r=1}^n \frac1n \approx \log n \quad \text{(in some sense)}.$$
Have a Google search for 'harmonic series' to find out more information -- other search engines are available! In particular, I'd recommend looking at the Wikipedia article, and specifically [this section of it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Rate_of_divergence). Hopefully this helps you! :)